# Plural form of number (issues of a journal) with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, formatting

There is no plural form for the term ‘number’, referring to an issue of a journal. I tried to define one (n<sup>os</sup>) but it's not sufficient to print it (e.g. article in a double issue).
What should I do? My style is verbose-trad2.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,language=french,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{numero.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}

\NewBibliographyString{numbers}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  numbers = {{num\'eros}{n\textsuperscript{os}}}
}

\begin{document}
citation\footcite{doe_life_2011}
\end{document}
```

numero.bib:

```
@article{doe_life_2011,
  title = {My Life},
  number = {137-138},
  journal = {{IJAS}},
  author = {Dan, {John}},
  pages = {139--153},
   date = {2011}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only printing the `number` bibstring doesn't take the new `numbers` string in account. You must check if the field is either a single number or a numeral range and then print it accordingly. In a very simplified way, you can use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{%
  \iffieldnum{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace}%
    {\iffieldnums{number}{\bibstring{numbers}\addnbspace}%
    {}}%
  #1}
```

It checks if the number field is a single number and uses the `number` bibstring if so, using the newly created `numbers` otherwise. Non-numerical fields will be printed *without* a any of the bibstrings. If you want to add the `number` bibstring to such fields you can to add it to the plural form check:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{%
  \iffieldnum{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace}%
    {\iffieldnums{number}{\bibstring{numbers}\addnbspace}%
    {\bibstring{number}\addnbspace}}%
  #1}
```

So that whenever there's a number field the `number` bibstring is used, using the `numbers` bibstring in plural forms.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{single-number,
    title = {An article in a single number of the journal},
    author = {John Doe},
    journal = {The Journal Title},
    number = {99},
    date = {2015},
  }
  @article{no-number,
    title = {An article without a journal number},
    author = {John Doe},
    journal = {Another Journal},
    volume = {10},
    date = {2015},
  }
  @article{multiple-numbers,
    title = {Article in multiple numbers of a journal},
    author = {John Doe},
    journal = {Yet another journal},
    number = {137-138},
    date = {2015},
  }
  @article{roman-number,
    title = {An article in a roman number of the journal},
    author = {John Doe},
    journal = {The Journal Title},
    number = {xii},
    date = {2015},
  }
  @article{non-numerical-number,
    title = {An article in a non-numerical journal number},
    author = {John Doe},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    number = {Three},
    date = {2015},
  }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,language=french,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{numbers}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  numbers = {n\textsuperscript{os}}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{%
  \iffieldnum{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace}%
    {\iffieldnums{number}{\bibstring{numbers}\addnbspace}%
    {}}%
  #1}

\begin{document}
\autocites{no-number,single-number,multiple-numbers,roman-number,non-numerical-number}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `biblatex` has the checks `\ifnumeral`/`\iffieldnum` as well as `\ifnumerals`/``\iffieldnums` which should allow more fine-grained control over the usage of `number` vs `numbers` vs. nothing at all. (Check `\blx@mkpageprefix` in `biblatex2.sty` for an example)

Comment: @moewe thanks, i added another check as you suggested. do you think this could be further improved?

Comment: Than you. As a matter of fact, I would have put the `\addnbsp` directly after the `\bibstrings` so as to not print one if no `\bibstring` was issued. I'm not sure whether there is any situation that would cause trouble though with your version. So you could say `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{%
  \iffieldnum{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace}
    {\iffieldnums{number}{\bibstring{numbers}\addnbspace}
    {}}%
  #1}` (modulo line breaks/`%`s, of course!).

Comment: @moewe `(-_Q)` Of course! Thank you so much! I fixed the code accordingly. @Carg please check the edited answer.

Comment: Hiya, it's me again! Now you have the problem that you suppress the `number` field if it is not recognised as a number. So if someone were to have `number = {Three}` in their `.bib` file, that would be ignored. But `biblatex` will still think it had printed the field, when it hadn't. I would suggest: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{%
  \iffieldnum{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace}
    {\iffieldnums{number}{\bibstring{numbers}\addnbspace}
    {}}%  #1%}` (again, modulo line breaks)

Comment: `biblatex`'s thinking it had printed the field, when it hadn't can seriously mess with the punctuation tracker.